# Get list with more elements in dictionary of lists

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary-comprehension

I've already seen several posts about dictionary of lists but none of them could help me so far. I have a dictionary of lists like:

```
dict = {'a': [1,5,4], 'b': [4], 'c': [1,5,4,3,8], 'd': [1,4]}
```

Now I want, in a loop, get the list with more elements, in this case the first list would be the "c" and next remove that list and start the loop again. I started by append the keys and the values of "dict" in a array (I don't know if this is necessary):

```
for key, value in dict.items():
    array_keys.append(str(key))
    array_values.append(dict[key])
```

Next, I tried to start the loop and to get the list with more elements I used:

```
max_list = max([len(i) in array_values])
```

With this I get "5" that is the maximum number of elements of values in the dictionary. I want to get the name of list, "c". Can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `max()` with a key function:

```
max(dictobject, key=lambda k: len(dictobject[k]))
```

This returns the key for which the value is longest.

Normally `max()` will compare the values of the iterable you give it, returning the element that'd be sorted last. If you pass a key function along, it'll return the value where `key(value)` will sort last. Here the key function returns the length of the value associated with the dictionary key.